# Auth button is not visible in Fabric Digits Integration

Tags: swift, twitter-fabric, swift2, fabric-digits

Hi I'm new to swift and currently I'm working on a project which was done before in swift 2.3 for both iPad and iPhone. My requirement is to use fabric digits framework as to sign up using the mobile number.I did everything as it is in the documentation but the pink color 'login with phone number' button is not appearing in my screen (UIViewController) for some reason. The code is bellow.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import DigitsKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var  phoneNum : String?
    let movement: CGFloat = 20.0
    var phoneHeight: CGFloat = 0.0
    var appURLs = AppURLs.sharedInstance
    var loadingView: UIView!
    var Id: Int!
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBAction func signUpButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyboard = switchStoryboards()
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignUpViewController")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        configureLoadingView()
        phoneHeight = self.view.frame.height
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = true
        self.username.delegate = self
        self.password.delegate = self
        self.slideMenuController()?.removeLeftGestures()
        let usernameImageView = UIImageView()
        if isIphone() {
            usernameImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 20)
        } else {
            usernameImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 30)
        }
        usernameImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Username")
        view.addSubview(usernameImageView)
        username.leftView = usernameImageView
        username.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

        let passwordImageView = UIImageView()
        if isIphone() {
            passwordImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 20)
        } else {
            passwordImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 54, height: 30)
        }
        passwordImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Password")
        view.addSubview(passwordImageView)
        password.leftView = passwordImageView
        password.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

        print("Login view did load loaded")

        let authButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                // TODO: associate the session userID with your user model
                let message = "Phone number: \(session!.phoneNumber)"
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You are logged in!", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: .None))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: .None)
            } else {
                NSLog("Authentication error: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        authButton?.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(authButton!)


    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
    }

    func configureLoadingView() {
        loadingView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
    }


    func loginAlerts(messages: String) {
        self.activity.stopAnimating()
        SwiftSpinner.show("Sign in Failed!", animated: false).addTapHandler({
            SwiftSpinner.hide()
            }, subtitle: messages)
    }
    func switchStoryboards() -> UIStoryboard {
        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .Phone:
            // It's an iPhone
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        case .Pad:
            return UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardiPad", bundle: nil)
            // It's an iPad
        case .Unspecified:
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            // Uh, oh! What could it be?
        default:
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        }
    }

    func isIphone() -> Bool {
        switch UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom {
        case .Phone:
            // It's an iPhone
            return true
        case .Pad:
            return false
            // It's an iPad
        case .Unspecified:
            return true
            // Uh, oh! What could it be?
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay in such instance all you have to do is to create a custom button in the relevant UI then all will works fine